# In the Romanian language standard accepted pronunciation, is **noștri** pronounced differently from **noștrii**?

Tags: pronunciation, romanian

In the Romanian language standard accepted pronunciation, is **noștri** pronounced differently from **noștrii**? Could you share any link to a document / book confirming this?

As a native speaker, I do not think there is a distinction, but at the same time, in 12 years of Romanian public school language and grammar classes, I have been taught that the language is phonetic, meaning that it is to be pronounced as it is written (whatever that means).

We are generally not taught in school about how a final **i** may indicate the palatalization of the preceding consonant (not the case here). I also recall that when pushed to answer such a question, a native Romanian speaker might pronounce **ii** as a diphthong, either /ij/ or /ji/, but this might just be a reaction under pressure, and am unaware of any "official" answer to this question.

Comment: Please  provide more information and what research you have done.

Comment: @Lambie I'm a native speaker who has spent 12 years in school studying the language at a native level

Comment: You misunderstand me. Perhaps you should read this: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask A native speaker? How is that relevant?

Comment: @Lambie the link you sent me is not about relevance, it's about not asking subjective questions. I'm asking about the standard pronunciation of two words, I wouldn't classify that as subjective

Comment: @Gabi Welcome. I think the question being asked of you is: what do you _think_ are the differences and have you done any digging to see if that is the case? Do they sound identical to you?

Comment: Yes, the Help link is about how to ask questions. You don't tell us what language those words are in. I mean it's not the recognizable **radii** is it?

Comment: Ah my apologies, I put the language in the tag, but not in the question title. Thanks for the feedback @jogloran and lambie

Answer (score 4):

*Noștrii* [doesn't exist](https://gresit.ro/nostri-sau-nostrii.html) in Romanian. It is never *written* like that.

The false impression that it could be otherwise comes from the influence of the form of the definite article for plural masculine *nouns* (*-i*: ”câini”=dogs, ”câinii”=the dogs): one might imagine adding the definite article to existing *noștri* (possessive pronoun, plural, masculine,"ours"): but the articulated form is *ai noștri* ([posessive article](https://gramaticalimbiiromane.ro/morfologia/parti-vorbire-flexibile/articolul/articolul-posesiv/))=”the ones that are ours”.

> I do not think there is a distinction

You are completely wrong.

The pronunciation of *noștri* is [*/ˈnoʃtri/*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/no%C8%99tri). That of *noștrii* (if that was a word) would be something like */ˈnoʃtrij/*, So, the answer to the question in title is "yes", *noștri* is to be pronounced differently from "noștrii" (but *noștrii* isn't a word!). That doesn't mean that the length of that last vowel cannot vary depending on context. But the general rule is that we *don't* have there a long *i*, like in *copii*=children, pronounced */koˈpij/*, where the vowel *i* is followed by de corresponding semivowel. – Romanian has 4 of each. On the Romanian vowels read [this](https://ro.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonologia_limbii_rom%C3%A2ne#Semivocale). – But one might say or at least [perceive phonologically](https://www.readingrockets.org/reading-101/reading-101-learning-modules/course-modules/phonological-and-phonemic-awareness) that it's longer than *i* in *striga* */striˈɡa/* (call, yell), and surely than in *bani* (”money”), *rupi* (”you break”), *lupi* (”wolves”) etc, where there is just an [asilabic vowel](https://ro.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonologia_limbii_rom%C3%A2ne#Vocala_asilabic%C4%83_/%E2%80%BFi/) (*/ban‿i/, /rup‿i/, /lup‿i/*).

Because Romanian speakers feel that they have longer or shorter vowels (which is true) but see a single written form (maybe an unfortunate situation), *and* believe the rule ”one sound one letter” to be real (which isn't!) they may tend to think that because letter *i* is sometimes pronounced rather short, longer pronunciations ask for a double-i. But the effective length has more possible degrees than what the written letters suggest at first glance.

Contrary to what many Romanians may think, Romanian doesn't have an absolute correspondence between writing and pronunciation. This is common knowledge when you research the language scientifically.

For example, *e* is pronounced *[i̯e]* at the beginning of personal pronouns and of the verb *to be/a fi*: written ‒ *eu, el, ea, ei, ele; e, este, ești, eram, erau*, pronounced ‒ *[i̯eu], [i̯el], [i̯ea], [i̯ei], [i̯ele]; [i̯e], [i̯este], [i̯ești], [i̯eram], [i̯erau]*.

See [this](https://foneticalimbiiromane.ro/ortografie-si-ortoepie/norme-ortografice-si-ortoepice/norme-ortografice-si-ortoepice-pentru-vocale/). —But at that very link, which is not a scientific as much as a pedagogical article, we can already see the problem: the author says repeatedly *it is written and pronounced e (not [i̯e])* or *it is written e but is pronounced [i̯e]*, as if *e* had an absolute way of pronunciation or at least a clear/usual/normal one, and an exceptional one. That is the case, in a way, but the formulation may implicitly suggest a rigidity which is not there!—

There could be given many other examples of situations where the same letters *have to* be pronounced very differently, although many people don't notice if asked about it, even if they do it (correctly). In ”unit” (unified) the *n* letter stands for a different sound than in ”ungur” (Hungarian): it's */uˈnit/* versus
*/ˈuŋ.ɡur/*. Rather famously and funny "un pic" (a bit) is felt by many as being "in fact" said "umpic", so that some people (given "we write as we speak") tend to write it "umpic"!

Anyway, *noștri, voștri* are to be pronounced like *aștri* (stars, luminaries), not like *aștrii* (the stars).

---

Now, considering

> we've been taught that *the language is phonetic, meaning that it is
> to be pronounced as it is written (whatever that means)

In fact, that rule is not absolute in Romanian, it only has a pedagogic value for early learners, but unfortunately (in my experience too), that limitation is not explained in later years of education, and many people —even teachers in the inferior levels— believe there is a such strict rule.

The unclear status of this rule in the public opinion seems to be a very problematic aspect, because it had an extraordinary and (in [my opinion](https://www.reddit.com/r/limbaromana/comments/148bf5p/%C3%AE_sau_%C3%A2_sunt_sau_s%C3%AEnt/?context=3), and in [that](https://jurnalul.ro/special-jurnalul/noi-scriem-cu-i-din-i-121659.html) of [many](https://dilemaveche.ro/sectiune/la-fata-timpului/despre-i-si-a-633408.html) [others](https://englishromanian.ro/blog/2014/10/08/norme-si-reglementari-ortografie-limba-romana-istoric-2/)) regrettable consequence: because the form *sunt* (I *am*, they *are*) was re-introduced through a reform in 1993, that ”rule” gave the impression that it *had to* be pronounced */sunt/*, when in fact the 'real' word, no matter its written form across the time, even centuries, has been always pronounced "sînt"-*/sɨnt/*. The *u* *pronunciation* is even being promoted as obligatory (!), when in fact the pronunciation */sunt/* is just a bad habit of half-learned people from the period 1932-1953 when *sunt* was re-introduced (was absent since 1904) although the explicit rule *then and always* during the history of *sunt* writing has been that it is to be *only **written** like that*, and pronounced sînt. Between 1904-1932 and 1953-1993 *sunt* didn't exist. Before 1904 it was written *sûnt* – but it was always pronounced like *sînt* (*/sɨnt/*) - just like "adevăr" (truth) was written "adevĕr", but always pronounced in the same way (*/a.deˈvər*), etc. Even now, the large majority follows the natural rule of saying the word, */sɨnt/*, in spite of the odd formal one, although its imposition during exams and basic education is slowly eroding the practice. Another scholarly opinion on that topic [here](https://dexonline.ro/article/Alf_Lombard_-_Despre_folosirea_literelor_%C3%AE_%C8%99i_%C3%A2). Also, a more polemic one [here](https://cabalinkabul.com/2013/01/06/mult-e-dulce-si-apoasa-despre-reforma-ortografiei/)).

Comment: Side note: you shouldn’t use back ticks (`) for emphasis or IPA – it denotes _code blocks_, and things like screen readers make a complete mess of those or skip them altogether, so someone accessing the text through a screen reader may end up missing half the content. I would also suggest cutting down on the parentheses a bit, but that’s just a matter of style.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I'll try. But are ticks not to be used at all on a site like this where code block is not present?

Comment: Generally speaking, no – if it’s not code, don’t wrap it in code tags. (We do sometimes have code blocks, primarily in questions about Praat scripts, corpus data analysis in R, etc., but it’s not that common.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I've removed all for IPA and replaced all ` with * (italics).